# What must I do with this Linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, operator-algebras

Can anyone help help me with this problem

I want to show that the operator $\mathscr{L}=u \partial/\partial y$, is not an linear operator.
This is what i got

$\mathscr{L}(au+bv)=u \partial/\partial y(au+bv) =u \partial/\partial y (au)+u \partial/\partial y(bv)=au\partial u/\partial y+bu\partial u/\partial y = a\mathscr{L}(u)+b\mathscr{L}(v)$

That seems linear to me, what did i do wrong?

Comment: It looks linear to me. You may want to be careful about using the symbol $u$ to denote two different things though.

Comment: Please write the definition carefully. On what space of functions is it acting?

Comment: I want to show that the PDE $u_x+uu_y=0$ is not linear.

Comment: So you have $\mathscr L(u)= uu_y$. Is $\mathscr L(2u)=2\mathscr L(u)$?

Comment: Since the constant is not within the differentiation, i not See why not? I find This a bit abstract

Comment: $\mathscr{L}(2u) = (2u)(2u)_y=4uu_y$, while $2\mathscr{L}(u) = 2uu_y$.

Comment: It seem by you comment, that the differential operator $\mathscr{L}$ is defined as in @TedShifrin comment. If this is true, please confirm or is $u$ a fixed function and $\mathscr{L}(v)=uv_y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your firts mistake is
$$\mathscr{L}(au+bv)=u \partial/\partial y(au+bv)$$ 
it should be
$\mathscr{L}(au+bv)=(au + bv) \partial/\partial y(au+bv)$

Answer (score 0):

Take functions $u$ and $v$ defined by $u(x,y)=y$ and $v(x,y)=x$. Then:  $$\mathscr{L}(u+v)=(u+v) (u+v)_y =  u u_y +vu_y = u+v,$$ 
while 
$$\mathscr{L}(u)+\mathscr{L}(v) = uu_y +vv_y = u.$$